# Gzip with web.config IIS 7.5 doesn't work

Tags: iis, web-config, gzip, iis-7.5

I'm using the following code in my web.config on the IIS 7.5 server to enable gzip but it doesn't work. The host says it is an error in my code. Can someone help me please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

      <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\
    temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
        <dynamicTypes>
          <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
          <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
        </staticTypes>
      </httpCompression>
      <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```